# What are the differences between 'like' and 'alike'?

Tags: synonyms

1. The two boys are *alike* in looks, but not in personality.
2. He's *like* his brother.

These two sentences have been taken from **Practical English Usage** by Swan. He said that use of *alike* in second sentence is wrong, but he didn't explain it. Please tell me why only *alike* is suitable for the first sentence, while *like* for the second.

Comment: "Alike" has only a ***predicative*** usage. That means it can't be placed before a noun. "Like" is a preposition.

Comment: Look further. A good dictionary to start with. Good Luck. See also: [ell.se]

Comment: @Hugh I said, "***That means it can't be placed before a noun***". Those are adverbial usages.

Comment: @Rathony  Shorter Oxfod says (Usually predicative) and ***predicative*** *alike* is about 10 times as common as ***post-positive qualifier*** *alike* . But " had access to Germany and France alike" and " board-games for girls and boys alike" can be found. Ngram "alike are" v. "are alike."

Comment: @Hugh I can understand why it is called "post-positive" qualifier. But it is an adverbial usage. If we start to discuss it, it will be a 10-day-without-lunch-break discussion.

Comment: @user140086, Re "*discussion*", ain't that point of this site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Like* can indicate pretty much any degree of similarity.
*Alike* is used when a high degree of similarity is being described.

**Like** is used when one person, or one set of persons, or any ONE entity, is being compared to someone or something.

**Alike** is used when two or more persons or things are being compared to one another.

Thus "is" can never be used with alike: it's always "are."

John and Peter are brothers.
John *is* a lot like Peter.
John and Peter *are* alike.

Comment: Hmm, §1. <John is alike Peter.> sounds good? §2. <Like Peter, John is.>? §3.  <Alike Peter, John is.>?

Answer (score 1):

Both **like** and **alike** may be used to tell similarity. On the other hand, **alike** -as an adverb -may also be used after you have referred to two people or groups, to mean ‘both’ or ‘equally’. Eg:

```
 Parents and teachers alike demanded reforms
```

Please check [freedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alike)

Comment: The question is about the "adjective" usage of both words. Not "adverbial".  (Downvote is not mine)