# 'Alike' or 'akin' or something else?

Tags: adjectives

Context:
I have started to write a blog post about my recent road trip.

Difficulty:
I was desperate to go for a trip and in that desperation, the planning was not up to the mark. My previous trip also began the same way. To highlight this fact, in the 'Prelude' section, I wrote a sentence as below:

> **Alike** my previous trip, this one was chalked out of desperation.

1. My proof-reader thinks that 'Alike' is not the right word, should be 'Akin'
2. I thought of using 'Similar' but that doesn't seem right either

Any inputs?

Comment: include the definitions of alike and akin in your question please.

Comment: Check the different dictionary definitions / usage notes for ***like*** and ***alike*** (your example uses the wrong one! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, should it be 'Like' or ...?

Comment: See [What are the differences between 'like' and 'alike'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288752/what-are-the-differences-between-like-and-alike), which was closed when asked previously on ELU. Probably because it's considered "Too Basic" here, but I certainly wouldn't have voted to close *your* question if it had been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: By the way, "I was desperate to go for a trip and in that desperation, the planning was not up to the mark" will always be understood in English and at the same time, it will always mark you out as non-native speaker.

"My previous trip also began the same way. To highlight this fact, in the 'Prelude' section, I wrote a sentence as below…" will mark you out in the same way…

Comment: "Like" or "Akin to".

Answer (score 2):

There are several options, which are pretty much equivalent in meaning, though there might be differences in style.

1. *Like my previous trip, ...* is fairly informal
2. *Akin to my previous trip, ...* sounds a bit highfalutin. Needs *to* after it
3. *As [with] my previous trip, ...* similar to option 1

There are undoubtedly more possibilities, but these are the ones I would consider. Depending on the style of your blog post I would probably go for the first one.

Oh, and *alike* is not an option here.

Comment: *As **with** my previous trip.* I don't think you can just use *as* alone like that.

Comment: @PeterShor I think it depends how the sentence continues (_As my previous trip, this was just a disaster._), but yes, this might be a further option.

Answer (score -1):

Alike usually end up at the end of the sentence,

I treat both the options alike.

I chalked this trip out of desperation much like the previous one.

Both my trips were chalked alike, out of desperation.

but Akin can be placed at the beginning of the sentence too!

Alike my previous trip, this one was chalked out of desperation.

Akin to my previous trip, this too was chalked out of desperation.

Comment: This answer would be improved with reputable references.

Comment: Why 'Alike'? Why can't it be, "Like my previous trip, this one was chalked out of desperation"?

Comment: It can be, of course, but for the interest of this particular topic, I kept the discussion narrowed down to Alike vs Akin